# Bluemix builds failing

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

Our Node.js project just stopped building this morning. We are getting errors that seem rather unrelated to changes we've been making:

```
    Cloning the 'master' branch from repo 'https://P90MSG01:3041/git/<me>/<app>'
Getting changes from revision 'fde39d89c2cdea23b795b598d3b4568c71ea520d' to revision 'c2034dcc1bc80daeb94fdfc28205ce8061f96125'
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONException: expecting either ',' or '}' on line 30, column 126
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseObject(Parser.java:220)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:335)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseArray(Parser.java:269)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:334)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseObject(Parser.java:211)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:335)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseArray(Parser.java:269)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:334)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseObject(Parser.java:211)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:335)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseArray(Parser.java:269)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:334)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseObject(Parser.java:211)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:335)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseArray(Parser.java:269)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:334)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseObject(Parser.java:211)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseValue(Parser.java:335)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parseArray(Parser.java:269)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parse(Parser.java:158)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.internal.Parser.parse(Parser.java:140)
    at org.apache.wink.json4j.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:142)
    at ids.sourcechange.SourceChangeParser.main(SourceChangeParser.java:57)

Finished: FAILED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were issues with code changes that were deployed last night.  Some of them have since been reverted.  I would try again and let us know.

Comment: It was failing just an hour ago, but just worked now!